# How to add protocol type as subview

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift-protocols, protocol-oriented

So I wrote a simple protocol:

```
protocol PopupMessageType{
    var cancelButton: UIButton {get set}
    func cancel()
}
```

and have a customView:

```
class XYZMessageView: UIView, PopupMessageType {
...
}
```

and then I currently have:

```
class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {

    //code...

    var messageView : CCPopupMessageView!
    private func setupUI(){
    view.addSubview(messageView)

    }

}
```

But what I want to do is:

```
class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {

    //code...

    var messageView : PopupMessageType!
    private func setupUI(){
    view.addSubview(messageView) // ERROR

    }

}
```

ERROR I get:

> Cannot convert value of type 'PopupMessageType!' to expected argument
>   type 'UIView'

**EDIT:**
I'm on Swift 2.3!

Comment: if let popupView = messageView as? UIView { view.addSubview(popupView)  }
else { // handle the case where messageView is not a UIView }

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401778/in-swift-how-can-i-declare-a-variable-of-a-specific-type-that-conforms-to-one-o

Comment: Swift 2.3 is deprecated and unsupported by any current tooling...for your own sake, please upgrade.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ [When you're In Canada, the 80s (of US) don't come to Canada til like 93](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0885872/quotes/qt0453933)

Comment: RIP how I met your mother :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the type of property **messageView** to **(UIView & PopupMessageType)!**

I mean

```
class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {

    //code...

    var messageView : (UIView & PopupMessageType)!
    private func setupUI(){
    view.addSubview(messageView) // ERROR

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean something other than `class XYZMessageView: UIView, PopupMessageType`? (I've already done that in my question)

Comment: @Honey I think he meant roughly the same thing as my answer does. The only difference is that I used a type alias in my answer.

Comment: @Sweeper, exactly :) +1 for you

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4 you can do this:

```
typealias PopupMessageViewType = UIView & PopupMessageType
```

And then use `PopupMessageViewType` as the type of the variable.

Comment: and if I'm not Swift 4?

Comment: @Honey Then you'll have to create a common base class that inherits from `UIView` and implements `PopupMessageType` and inherit everything else from that base class.

Comment: basically make the requirement a 'special' subclass, not a protocol. Though that special subclass conforms to a protocol and is also subclassed from UIView? meh ugly. But I get it. No other easy alternative?

Comment: @Honey as far as I'm concerned, no.

Comment: @Honey I suppose you can make a wrapper class around the object and provide two computed properties to access which one you need.

Comment: @Calimari328 can you write an answer for that?

Answer (score 2):

DISCLAIMER: I do not have the swift 2.3 compiler anymore since swift 4 is the new normal for iOS development.  The following code may possibly need tweaks to get it working in swift 2.3

---

Essentially we will be making a 2x1 mux where the two inputs are the same object.  The output depends on whether you set the mux to choose the first or the second one.

```
// The given protocol
protocol PopupMessageType{
    var cancelButton: UIButton {get set}
    func cancel()
}

// The object that conforms to that protocol
class XYZMessageView: UIView, PopupMessageType {
    var cancelButton: UIButton = UIButton()
    func cancel() {
    }
}

// The mux that lets you choose the UIView subclass or the PopupMessageType
struct ObjectPopupMessageTypeProtocolMux<VIEW_TYPE: UIView> {
    let view: VIEW_TYPE
    let popupMessage: PopupMessageType
}

// A class that holds and instance to the ObjectPopupMessageTypeProtocolMux
class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {
    var messageWrapper : ObjectPopupMessageTypeProtocolMux<UIView>!
    private func setupUI(){
        view.addSubview(messageWrapper.view)
    }
}

//...
let vc = PopUpViewController() // create the view controller
let inputView = XYZMessageView() // create desired view

// create the ObjectPopupMessageTypeProtocolMux
vc.messageWrapper = ObjectPopupMessageTypeProtocolMux(view: inputView, popupMessage: inputView) //<-- 1

vc.messageWrapper.view // retreive the view
vc.messageWrapper.popupMessage.cancel() // access the protocol's methods
vc.messageWrapper.popupMessage.cancelButton // get the button
```

1) I input the "inputView" twice for the initializer of ObjectPopupMessageTypeProtocolMux.  They are the same class instance, but they get casted to different types.

I hope this helps you get to where you wanna go in swift 2.3

Comment: what's a "2x1 mux"?

Comment: It’s a type of logic gate where you have two inputs but one output.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer